# using entity classes to access google sql

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a android app with a google engine backend.  In order for the android app to communicate with the google app engine app, i need entity classes, with which I would generate endpoint classes.  Then after generating a library for those endpoint classes i can use them as an API.  My question, is since the endpoint classes access the datastore, is there way to get them to access a google sql instance instead?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Cloud Endpoints and Datastore are unrelated technologies, there's no reason why your backend code can't access Cloud SQL instead. Any specific reason you want to switch from Datastore to Cloud SQL?

Comment: Hi, Philipp, because I will have multiple applications accessing the cloud sql database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google App Engine entities specifically work with the GAE Datastore.

However there is nothing forcing you to use entities - you can create a Google Cloud Endpoints API that saves data to MySQL by directly sending SQL queries or using an Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) such as [SQLAlchmey](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).